# ethers.js can't handle functions with variant call signature?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I get type errors in hardhat when my contracts have two versions of the same function  which differ only by call signature, i.e.

```
contract MyContract {

 string memory public _defaultVersion ="1.0.0"

 function addParameter(string memory paramName) public {
    addParameter(paramName, _defaultVersion);
 }

 function addParameter(string memory paramName, string memory version) public {
    [code to add a parameter]
 }
}
```

I don't get a compile error, but when I run `hardhat test` which includes a call to `addParameter` I get `TypeError: myContract.addBindingParameter is not a function`, no matter which call signature I use.  If I delete one of the functions from my contract the test runs normally.  (This doesn't appear to be a problem with function calls inside the solidity contract which appear to properly discriminate between the function calls based on the supplied parameters).

Is it possible to use these variant function (same function name, different params) with hardhat/ethers?  If so what's the proper way to call?

Comment: Check this: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/migration/web3/-%23-migration-from-web3-js--contracts--overloaded-functions